# phonegap facebook login plugin does not work

Tags: facebook, cordova

New facebook Window (or Activity) is closed right after opened.

Why does it happen?

My code:

```
function facebook_login() {
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_info"],function(userData) {
                console.log("facebook login success");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
                // navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("facebook login error");
                console.log(error);
                // navigator.notification.alert(error);
            });
        }
```

cordova 3.4

Android API min 14, max 19

plugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git

[Log Cat in Eclipse]

[image]

Comment: Does console show anything? success or error?

Comment: @AtanuCSE : Thank you for your answer. There is nothing in console.